# Unable to get redux form checkbox working in bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-redux-form

I am trying to use Bootstrap Checkbox input in React Redux Form, i am unable to see the values in output.

I have this code working fine with Semantic UI

```
export const renderCheckbox = ({ input, label }) => {
  return (
    <Form.Field>
      <Checkbox
        label={label}
        checked={input.value ? true : false}
        onChange={(e, { checked }) => input.onChange(checked)}
      />
    </Form.Field>
  );
}
```

Attempted to do the same in Bootstrap fails

```
export const renderCheckbox = ({ input, label }) => {
  return (
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Check 
        label={label}
        checked={input.value ? true : false}
        onChange={(e, { checked }) => input.onChange(checked)}
      />
    </Form.Group>
  );
}
```

I end up with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'checked' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
onChange

  125 |   <Form.Check 
  126 |     label={label}
  127 |     checked={input.value}
> 128 |     onChange={(e, { checked }) => input.onChange(checked)}
      | ^  129 |   />
  130 | </Form.Group>
  131 |
```

this how it looks in the rendered form

```
<Field
                    name="email_consent"
                    id="email_consent"
                    type="checkbox"
                    component={renderCheckbox}
                    label="I would like to receive email offers"
                />
```

This is what i ended up doing, not sure if this was best practise

```
<div className="form-check">
                        <Field name="email_consent"
                        id="email_consent"
                        component="input"
                        className="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox" 
                        label="I would like to receive email offers"/>
                        <label className="form-check-label" for="email_consent">Check me out</label>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn’t you replace Form.Check by Checkbox?

Comment: Not if i follow the instruction here: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/forms/#forms-form-check

Form.Check is the correct syntax